# Samsung Galaxy Tab size on run time

Tags: android

How to get Samsung Galaxy Tab size on run time? 
If I use

```
Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
int width = display.getWidth();
```

It gives 320*480 size. But its not the tab size.
Is there any other way to get the tab size in runtime?.

Thanks,
Yuvaraj.K

Comment: this is a display dimension. What particular size do you want to get? And why?

Comment: Developing an android application which will support both mobile and tab. SO I need the device size for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer:

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();

getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);

int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
```